# How to set tab text color when programmatically creating tab

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I've created my tab in my onCreate method without a tabhost. How do I set the text color programmatically as well? This is in a relative layout with id=relativeLayoutTimeline if that helps.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    Tab tabHome = actionBar.newTab().setText("Home").setTag("HomeTimelineFragment")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.home_icon).setTabListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly Michael. You'd be much better off doing this in a style like this.

```
<!-- The theme for the activity -->
<style name="TabSpecialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Modify the text color -->
<style name="TabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
  <item name="android:textColor">#F70000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to create a TextView for your tabs text, set the Customview property for each tab.

```
TextView tView = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
tView.setText(tab_name);
tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);  

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()  
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setCustomView(tView));
```